# Using interpolate on pandas data frame and getting "no axis named 1" error

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I am looking to interpolate total revenue values in a data frame using the interpolate function.

I've tried changing the arguments I have provided to interpolate, like the following:

```
useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"].interpolate('linear',1)
useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"].interpolate('linear',0)
useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"].interpolate('nearest',1)
useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"].interpolate('nearest',0)
```

My code is below:

```
for i in range(0, len(useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"])):
    if useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"][i] == 0 or np.isnan(useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"][i]):
        print("success 2")
        useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"][i] = useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"].interpolate('nearest',1)
print(useducation_df["TOTAL_REVENUE"])
```

I get the following error:

ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.interpolate()` is used to fill the missing values in a Series or Dataframe object. The documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html).
A Series object does not have an axis attribute, hence the error.
Remove the `[axis =] 1` (second positional argument) in `.interpolate()`